# Value of date changes in scala when reading from yaml file

Tags: scala, yaml

I have a YAML file, which has data -

```
time:
  - days : 50
  - date : 2020-02-30
```

I am reading both the things in my scala program -

```
val t = yml.get(time).asInstanceOf[util.Arraylist[util.LinkedHashMap[String, Any]]]
val date = t.get(1)
```

this output of date is - `{date=Sat Feb 29 19:00:00 EST 2020}`
or if I put the value in yaml file as `date: 2020-02-25` the output will be `{date=Mon Feb 24 19:00:00 EST 2020}` and not `{date=Tue Feb 25 19:00:00 EST 2020}`.

Why is it always reducing the date value by 1?
Any help is highly appreciated.

PS - I want to validate the date; that is why the input is `date: 2020-02-30`

Comment: PS - If I enter the input as 
date: 2020-02-31
then scala code automatically converts itself to March 1st. Is this the inbuilt functionality of scala that I am not aware of?

Comment: EST is 5 hours behind UTC, so it's worth noting that 2020-02-25 at midnight UTC is 2020-02-24 at 19:00 EST.

Comment: @LeviRamsey. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: It would depend on how you're getting the value `yml` (e.g. which library you're using to parse the YAML file and whether it allows treating a date as something other than a DateTime or Instant).

Comment: Ok. I am using snakeyaml, and this library automatically converts ```2020-02-25``` as the date (if the type is not specified), but I am not sure why it is only accepting UTC.

Comment: Assuming that we're talking about `java.util.Date` and friends, that's not actually a date but a representation of an instant in time in UTC.

Comment: Also note that per the YAML spec (https://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html): "The time part may be omitted altogether, resulting in a date format. In such a case, the time part is assumed to be 00:00:00Z (start of day, UTC)"

Comment: Not having any experience with snakeyaml, it might be possible to provide it with a different strategy for dealing with dates.